# how to split a string in groups of multiple variables

Tags: python

I have a string

```
'abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh'
```

and i want to split it in 3 string of 8 variables:

```
'abcdefgh','12345678' and 'abcdefgh'
```

but i get a list of 3 strings:

```
['abcdefgh', '12345678', 'abcdefgh']
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Is it always 8 characters? If so, what difficulty are you facing with that?

Comment: `re.findall(r'.{8}', s)` or  `re.findall(r'.{1,8}', s)`

Comment: @AnandSKumar i want to get 3 strings and i get a list of 3 strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = 'abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh'
import re

a, b, c = re.findall("\w{8}", s)
print(a, b, c)

a, b, c = (s[i:i + 8] for i in range(0, len(s), 8))
print(a, b, c)
```

Comment: @Anders, the upper bound is not inclusive so `s[0:8]` would be 8 characters `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7`.`s[0:7] -> abcdefg`

Comment: if i use one value for example 'a' it gives a list instead of 3 values like this `['abcdefgh', '12345678', 'abcdefgh']`

Comment: @svs, how would you split a single character into 3?

Comment: yes i have the list `'abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh'` and i want to split it into 3 strings `'abcdefgh' , '12345678' , 'abcdefgh'`

Comment: i mean the string 'abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh'

Comment: That is what  `(s[i:i + 8] for i in range(0, len(s), 8))` is doing,  do you mean you want to split  a string into `n` parts without knowing how long s may be?

Comment: yes, but i want n strings and not a list of n strings

Comment: `a, b, c = (s[i:i + 8] for i in range(0, len(s), 8))` gives you three strings, it unpacks from the generator, how do you propose you are going to hold the strings if not in an iterable?

Comment: and can i have one variable that contains the 3 strings? for example:         `a = (s[i:i + 8] for i in range(0, len(s), 8))` because it's then that i get the list

Comment: @svs, not unless you use a list, tuple etc.., you cannot store more than one string using a single variable unless you use some container to store the references

Answer (score 1):

In Python, strings works sort of like arrays. You can access individual letters as elements in an array using brackets (`[]`). This means that your problem can be solved like this:

```
whole = 'abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh'
part1 = whole[0:8]    #abcdefgh
part2 = whole[8:16]   #12345678
part3 = whole[16:24]  #abcdefgh
```

Please note that if the string is shorter than 24 characters this will give you and index out of bounds error.

Or, if you want it directly in an array you can simply do it like this:

```
parts = [whole[0:8], whole[8:16], whole[16:24]]
```

But that is a bit repetitive. Lets find a better way to do it.

```
parts = [whole[i*8:(i+1)*8] for i in range(len(whole)//8)]
```

This will give you `whole` in 8 character long parts no matter how long it is, simply ignoring any extra parts at the end that does not fit into a full 8 character block. In the example of a 24 character string it would loop with `i` being equal to 0, 1 and 2 giving you exactly the same intervals as in the examples above.

Comment: `whole[0:7]` is `"abcdefg"` not `"abcdefhg"`

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it. Obviously to long since I actually wrote some Python.